# What is the meaning of "ärmelschonend"?

Tags: meaning

Does anyone know what the meaning of "ärmelschonend" is?
I assume it is some kind of "Redewendung", but I'm not sure.

Comment: @RHa I admit that you are right, that it is a compositive adjective, but I do not follow your conclusion that hence it cannot be a colloquial figure of speech ("Redewendung"). These are totally different categories and they are not mutually exclusive. In fact, I think, _ärmelschonend_ is both, a compositive adjective which is also a figure of speech.

Comment: @jonathan.scholbach Without context (hint, hint) it is hard to tell whether *ärmelschonend* is a colloquial figure of speech or if it is to be taken literally (maybe the text is about protective sleeves?), although the former is quite likely.

Comment: I would classify the word as rarely used. So, the following is to be regarded with a good portion of suspicion. But - I have never seen this word being used with its literal meaning - do you?

Comment: Why did you tag this with "meaning in context", but then didn't provide any context?

Comment: @RHa I concede that the question could and should have been improved by adding the context of _ämelschonende Arbeit_. But besides that, it would be better for us (giving answers) to point the thread opener directly to that problem of their question instead of giving an answer, which probably (and foreseeably) doesn't help them.

Comment: Conteeeeeeeeext!

Comment: Nachdem nach so vielen Rufen nach Kontext keinerlei Ergänzung der Frage mehr folgte, votiere ich sie jetzt runter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct in assuming that this is a colloquial figure of speech.

It is used to denote a type of work which is not physically exhausting, but rather work in an office. I would say, that it has a (slightly) pejorative tone. I think so because of the following semantical associations:

*Ärmelschoner* are a piece of clothing worn by clerks, to protect the sleeves from being polluted with ink (see https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%84rmelschoner). So, I think, *ärmelschonend* has the subtext of addressing that the work is not exhaustive, similar to *Schreibtischtäter*, which also has a pejorative connotation (even when it is not used do denote officials in the 3rd Reich).

Also there is semantical link to the colloquial figure of speech *sich nicht die Hände schmutzig machen* (*to not pollute one's hands with dirt*), which also refers to "someone else is doing the real work for you". So, *ärmelschonende Arbeit* is a type of
 work where someone ist not polluting their sleeves / their hands with dirt.

All these critical, if not pejorative connotations stem from the fact that, in *ärmelschonende Arbeit*, "schonen" (*preserve*, *spare*, *prevent from damage*) stands in a contrast to the noun "Arbeit" (work).

Comment: I'm the one who asked the question, and thank you very much about your answer. It's really helpful!

Comment: Also see: *Ärmelschoner* ←→ *Knieschoner*.

Comment: @Janka  Ja, aber Knieschoner verwendet man gerade bei Arbeiten, die die Knie stark beanspruchen. Eine *ärmelschonende Arbeit* (wenn man das, ohne den Kontext erfahren zu haben, so vermuten darf) wäre ja wohl andersherum gerade eine Arbeit, die so wenig beanspruchend ist, dass *nicht mal* die Ärmel (nämlich auf dem Schreibtisch) abgenutzt werden. Oder?

Comment: Genau so ist es.

Comment: @ChristianGeiselmann Nein, so ist es nicht. Man trägt Ärmelschoner weil die Hemdsärmel besonders beansprucht werden - als Buchhalter allerdings nur von der Tinte. Und wie bei Wikipedia zu erfahren gibt es auch Ärmelschoner im Lebensmittelbereich, bei Schweißern etc. Und all die laufen durchaus, wie unser Buchhalter, Gefahr, sich die Hände zu verschmutzen, denn Hand und Arm sind zwei unterschiedliche Gliedmaßen. Allerdings lässt sich die Hand leichter reinigen als ein Hemdsärmel und die anderen benutzen wohl meist separate Handschuhe, die sie häufiger abnehmen müssen, während die ÄS anbleiben.

Comment: @userunknown   Der Zweck von Ärmelschonern ist mir durchaus bewusst. Jedoch war in der Frage von *ärmelschonend* die Rede. Das ist - was immer der Kontext auch sein mag - eindeutig etwas anderes als *Ärmelschoner erfordernd*. *Ärmelschonend* kann z.B. eine Arbeit sein, die eben die Ärmel nicht belastet oder angreift. Ärmelschonend ist natürlich auch der Ärmelschoner selbst. Aber das bräuchte man wohl nicht eigens zu sagen. Außer man hätte einen nicht ärmelschonenden Ärmelschoner, also ein misslungenes Produkt.

Comment: PS Ich kann mir als Verwendung für *ärmelschonend* allenfalls noch vorstellen, das in Vorschriften zum Verhalten in der Werkstatt aufgeführt ist, dass ärmelschonende Arbeitsweisen ärmelbelastenden Arbeitsweisen vorzuziehen sind, also z.B.: *Stützen Sie die Ellenbogen nicht auf die Werkbank.* Ich finde aber, der Originalfrager sollte uns wirklich endlich sagen, wo er dieses so gut wie unnütze Wort her hat.

Comment: Der Fragensteller hat doch im Grunde schon signalisiert, dass es um _ärmelschonende Arbeit_ geht, sonst hätte er doch die Antwort nicht akzeptiert.

Comment: Ja, der Kontext ist entscheidend. Ich bin erwachsen geworden ohne je Ärmelschoner gesehen zu haben - vielleicht mal im Film, aber so dezente, dass sie mir nicht aufgefallen sind. Bei "ärmelschonender Arbeit" neige ich dazu an eine Arbeit zu denken, bei der man  Ärmelschoner trägt - das mag natürlich falsch sein. Es ist aber auch kein gebräuchlicher Ausdruck, so dass man sagen könnte, was richtig ist und was falsch, soweit ich weiß. Wenn mir jmd. in einem YT-Video aber gänzlich unmetaphorisch erklärt "so wechselst Du die Fahrradkette ärmelschonend" würde ich das wahrscheinlich gar nicht merken.